# Display the output while looping in php

Tags: php

Is it possible to display string on the browser while in infinite loop? This is what I want to happen:

```
while(1) {
     echo "should display these lines on browser while in infinite loop.<br>";
}
```

Comment: 0_0  Why would you purposefully enter an infinite loop without any break point?  Without testing this, I suspect that it'll just cause a server-side overflow and die, showing nothing client-side.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  PHP doesn't output to the browser until it's done executing, usually.  You can try to add `flush();` after the `echo`.

Comment: I really hope this is a HUGELY simplified example.

Comment: I wanted to know if it is possible. I tried the code but for 50 lines and the display is shown after the loop. How is this possible in infinite loops? Or am I missing something or not possible at all?

Comment: how is 50 lines NEARLY enough for you to notice whether it's immidiate or after the loop finishes?

Comment: Why do you have an infinite loop?  Do you have a condition to break the loop?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to [flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) the output to the browser if you want it to appear immediately:

```
while(1) {
     echo "should display these lines on browser while in infinite loop.<br>";
     flush();
}
```

Chances are that whatever you're trying to accomplish, this isn't how you should go about it.

PHP will eventually time-out, but not before it generates a *massive* HTML document that your browser will have trouble displaying.

Comment: Note the web server may do its own buffering on top of this, particularly if it is doing gzip compression on data sent to the browser

Comment: Note however that like any php script it will eventually timeout. Default is 30 sec

Answer (score 6):

Notice the use of `ob_flush();` to make sure php outputs, and `usleep(100000)` to have time to see things happening.

```
while(1) {
     echo "should display these lines on browser while in infinite loop.<br>";
     usleep(100000); // debuging purpose
     ob_flush();
     flush();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add [`flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) after the echo statement, it will flush the output to the browser. Note that browsers generally don't start to render until their reach a certain amount of information (around .5kB).

```
while(1) {
     echo "should display these lines on browser while in infinite loop.<br>";
     flush(); //Flush the output buffer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to put flush(); after each echo of your code:

Set this in your php.ini:

> implicit_flush = Off

Or if you don't have access to php.ini:

> @ini_set('implicit_flush',1);